# Finding minimum from ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, peak-detection

I have Table with 10000 elements in it and I plot a graphic using ListPlot.
[image]

I need find minimum in graph.
[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GwEY4rukz9gosi6SaFdO0DBUythm_9jl/view?usp=sharing) is a .txt file with data.

I tried to use

```
Min[Data[[All,1]]]
```

the result is `0.`, cuz it search the first point of `x` but I don't need the first one.

Comment: `Data[[Ordering[Data[[All,2]],1][[1]],1]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would go about it:

```
minIndex = data[[All, 2]] // MinDetect // PositionIndex;
```

Now all the positions of the minima were collected in an `Association` and given the key `1`. We now want to split the list of minima positions into sublists that are "connected", e.g. where each position is separated by a distance of 1. From these sublists we only need the first and the last positions (the "corners"):

```
minPositions = minIndex[1] // RightComposition[
    Split[#, #1 == #2 - 1 &] & (* distance could be made more "soft" of course *)
    , Part[#, All, {1, -1}] &
    , Flatten
]
```

> {1, 276, 1167, 2844}

We now `Extract` the data points for these positions dropping the first, which you do not need as you said:

```
minPoints = Extract[data, List /@ minPositions] // Drop[#, 1] &
```

> {{0.275, 0.}, {1.166, 0.}, {2.843, 0.}}

Finally:

```
ListPlot[ data, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> Large, Point@minPoints }, ImageSize -> Large ]
```

[image: ListPlot of data with minima]

Answer (score 4):

```
lp = ListLinePlot[data, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
  Mesh -> {{Min[data[[All, 2]]]}},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, -.01}]
```

[image]

To extract the data elements:

```
Cases[Normal @ lp, Point[x_] :> x, All]
```

> {{0., 0.}, {0.275, 0.}, {1.166, 0.}, {2.843, 0.}}

If you want to remove the first point:

```
lp /. Point[x_] :> Point[Rest @ x]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
MinimalBy[Data, Last]
```

If you have runs of minimal elements and only want the first and last one: assuming that the grid spacing is 0.001 and inserting 10% of tolerance,

```
Split[MinimalBy[Data, Last], #2[[1]]-#1[[1]] <= 0.0011 &][[All, {1,-1}]]
```

maybe combined with `Flatten` to make into a single list of points.